# Fail in installing libcurl4-gnutls-dev in AWS ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, libcurl, apt-get

I try to do the following install (in order to upgrade git)

```
$sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

and i get these errors:

```
After this operation, 13.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main libtasn1-3 amd64 2.7-1ubuntu1.1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main libgnutls26 amd64 2.8.6-1ubuntu2.1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main libk5crypto3 amd64 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.3
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main libgssapi-krb5-2 amd64 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.3
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main libkrb5-3 amd64 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.3
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main libkrb5support0 amd64 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.3
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main libgssrpc4 amd64 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.3
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main libkadm5clnt-mit7 amd64 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.3
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main libkdb5-4 amd64 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.3
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main libkadm5srv-mit7 amd64 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.3
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main libldap-2.4-2 amd64 2.4.23-6ubuntu6.1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main krb5-multidev amd64 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.3
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main libcurl3-gnutls amd64 7.21.3-1ubuntu1.5
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main libgpg-error-dev amd64 1.10-0.2ubuntu1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main libgcrypt11-dev amd64 1.4.6-4ubuntu2
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main libtasn1-3-dev amd64 2.7-1ubuntu1.1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main libgnutls-dev amd64 2.8.6-1ubuntu2.1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main pkg-config amd64 0.25-1.1ubuntu1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main libidn11-dev amd64 1.18-1build1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main libkrb5-dev amd64 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.3
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main libldap2-dev amd64 2.4.23-6ubuntu6.1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main libcurl4-gnutls-dev amd64 7.21.3-1ubuntu1.5
  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libt/libtasn1-3/libtasn1-3_2.7-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnutls26/libgnutls26_2.8.6-1ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libk5crypto3_1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libgssapi-krb5-2_1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libkrb5-3_1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libkrb5support0_1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libgssrpc4_1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libkadm5clnt-mit7_1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libkdb5-4_1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libkadm5srv-mit7_1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openldap/libldap-2.4-2_2.4.23-6ubuntu6.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/krb5-multidev_1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl3-gnutls_7.21.3-1ubuntu1.5_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgpg-error/libgpg-error-dev_1.10-0.2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11-dev_1.4.6-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libt/libtasn1-3/libtasn1-3-dev_2.7-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnutls26/libgnutls-dev_2.8.6-1ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pkg-config/pkg-config_0.25-1.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libi/libidn/libidn11-dev_1.18-1build1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libkrb5-dev_1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openldap/libldap2-dev_2.4.23-6ubuntu6.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl4-gnutls-dev_7.21.3-1ubuntu1.5_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

What should I do?  looks like the url has been changed. 
I have updated the hosts file with this:

```
72.21.214.200 s3-1-w.amazonaws.com
72.21.214.200 us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com.s3.amazonaws.com
72.21.214.200 us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com
```

but when I do:

```
$curl http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

I still get access denied.  and I still cannot do the apt-get update.

Hmm looks like old release of Ubuntu I'm using.. 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release/91821#91821n